# loadView cannot access my property, throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a property that gets set when initiating a new view controller.

```
- (IBAction)headerPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    RouteViewController *route = [[RouteViewController alloc] initWithRoute:[[Route getRoute:TEST_ROUTE] autorelease]];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:circle animated:NO];
}
```

in the new view, which is a UIViewController

**RouteViewController.h**

```
@interface =RouteViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate> {
    Route *r;
}

-(id)initWithRoute:(Route *)route;


@property (retain, nonatomic) Route *r;
```

**RouteViewController.m**

```
-(id)initWithRoute:(Route *)route{
    self = [super init];

    r = route;

    return self;
}
- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];

    NSLog(@"TEST: %d", r.Route);  // throws exception. Actually ANY time I access my r property

}
```

r.Route is the int value that the const `TEST_ROUTE` contains.

NOW, when I setup my breakpoint, AT the time of the NSLog, the inspector shows my object contains

```
Self >
    r >
       Route: 1
```

and

```
r >
    Route: 1
```

So the property is available, and it DOES contain the correct data. But when i try ACCESSING the property, it throws an EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Thoughts? :) (This is killing me here!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems here:

`RouteViewController *route = [[RouteViewController alloc] initWithRoute:[[Route getRoute:TEST_ROUTE] autorelease]];`

I think the autorelease message should be sent to the `RouteViewController` here and not the `Route` object, as the `getRoute` method should return an autoreleased object due to the naming convention.

i.e.

```
RouteViewController *route = [[[RouteViewController alloc] initWithRoute:[Route getRoute:TEST_ROUTE]] autorelease];
```

You need to retain ownership of the Route object passed into the `initWithRoute` method:

Either:

```
-(id)initWithRoute:(Route *)route{
    self = [super init];

    r = [route retain];

    return self;
}
```

or:

```
-(id)initWithRoute:(Route *)route{
    self = [super init];

    self.r = route;

    return self;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate not only answering fast, but answering correctly, WITH additional information AND alternative methods, AND without questioning why something was done the way it was (im kinda looking at your Matt >_> Projects passed to me from someone else with no opportunity to clean anything up :p )

Comment: As mentioned in another answer, im far more used to ARC, I had no idea I had to "retain" right there.    Might have also been helpful if XCode had held my hand a little bit more obviously than "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" lol

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're not using ARC, but you're also not retaining route in your init method. Change this:

```
r = route;
```

to this:

```
r = [route retain];
```

Comment: Or better yet, enable ARC and use properties rather than directly accessing instance variables.

Comment: That was the magic word! Yes i am an iOS5 developer and I use primarily ARC, this belongs to a legacy project for 4.3.